# GoLang SSH Commands with slashes seem to instantly fail

Tags: go, ssh

I'm currently writing an app that given a parameter, will run a command on a remote server.  I'm using the /x/crypto/ssh package, everything seems to go smoothly if I use one liner commands like "who" or "ls", however, if I run a more complex command such as:

"grep SOMEDATA /var/log/logfile.log"

the program immediately exits and the command execution line with nothing more than "process exited with status 1", and I don't get anything else back.

If I check the history of the user I'm having it SSH into the remote system as, I do not see the command running at all.

Has anyone else run into this type of issue before?  Here's a snippet of the code I'm using to execute this (sensitive data removed of course):

```
func returnData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
var b bytes.Buffer
hostKey, err := getHostKey("SERVERNAME")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

err = r.ParseForm()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "USERNAME",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.Password("TESTPASS"),
    },
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.FixedHostKey(hostKey),
}

client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "SERVERNAME:22", config)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Creating Client Failed: ", err)
}

session, err := client.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Creating new Session Failed: ", err)
}

session.Stdout = &b
inputData := r.Form["fname"][0]
cmdExecute := fmt.Sprintf(`sudo grep %v /var/log/logfile.log`, inputData)
log.Println(cmdExecute)
if err := session.Run(cmdExecute); err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Getting Data From session Failed: ", err)
    log.Fatalln(b.String())
}
//log.Println(hostKey)
defer session.Close()
```

Comment: Do your "simple" commands also fail if you add an option to them? Say, run `who --login` or `ls -1`—do they work or fail?

Comment: They do indeed work with options, even if I pass them in through my webform or directly through Session.Run()

Comment: add a destination for session.Stderr too. That might give more clues. might be os.Stderr.

Comment: unfortunately stderr just prints 0.

Comment: :! could it be related to sudo ? Could it be that stdin not being set something weird occurs ? Could it be that it requires absolute path of the bin program ? could it be related to inputData having blankspace or so ?

Comment: Touche! It seems to be sudo, unfortunately I need to use it on the servers I'm running this against, I now wonder what would be stopping that.  I have noticed I do not see the commands I'm running in that user's history regardless, so now I'm wondering how its logging in and performing these commands.

Comment: although, seems weird you have no output on stderr. I would really try to setup stdin. Besides, consider the system environment setup, consider if this is a password less user or not. If not, you ll have to deal with the sudo challenge.

Comment: I'll attempt to possibly send it through stdin instead, luckily a password isn't necessary to use sudo with the commands I'm sending.  Thanks!